# Output file not created when running a R command in a Nextflow file?

Tags: kubernetes, nextflow

I am trying to run a nextflow pipeline but the output file is not created.

The main.nf file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2 

process my_script {

    """
    Rscript script.R
    """
}

workflow {
  my_script 
}
```

In my nextflow.config I have:

```
process {
   executor = 'k8s'
   container = 'rocker/r-ver:4.1.3'
}
```

The script.R looks like this:

```
 FUN <- readRDS("function.rds");
 input = readRDS("input.rds");
 output = FUN(
singleCell_data_input = input[[1]], savePath = input[[2]], tmpDirGC = input[[3]]
);
 saveRDS(output, "output.rds")
```

After running **nextflow run main.nf**  the output.rds is not created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nextflow processes are run independently and isolated from each other from inside the working directory. For your script to be able to find the required input files, these must be localized inside the process working directory. This should be done by defining an [`input`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#inputs) block and declaring the files using the [`path`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-path) qualifier, for example:

```
params.function_rds = './function.rds'
params.input_rds = './input.rds'


process my_script {

    input:
    path my_function_rds
    path my_input_rds

    output:
    path "output.rds"

    """
    #!/usr/bin/env Rscript

    FUN <- readRDS("${my_function_rds}");
    input = readRDS("${my_input_rds}");
    output = FUN(
      singleCell_data_input=input[[1]], savePath=input[[2]], tmpDirGC=input[[3]]
    );
    saveRDS(output, "output.rds")
    """
}

workflow {

    function_rds = file( params.function_rds )
    input_rds = file( params.input_rds )

    my_script( function_rds, input_rds )
    my_script.out.view()
}
```

In the same way, the script itself would need to be localized inside the process working directory. To avoid specifying an absolute path to your R script (which would not make your workflow portable at all), it's possible to simply embed your code, making sure to specify the Rscript shebang. This works because process scripts are not limited to Bash<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#scripts-a-la-carte)</sup>.

Another way, would be to make your Rscript executable and move it into a directory called `bin` in the the root directory of your project repository (i.e. the same directory as your 'main.nf' Nextflow script). Nextflow automatically adds this folder to the `$PATH` environment variable and your script would become automatically accessible to each of your pipeline processes. For this to work, you'd need some way to pass in the input files as command line arguments. For example:

```
params.function_rds = './function.rds'
params.input_rds = './input.rds'


process my_script {

    input:
    path my_function_rds
    path my_input_rds

    output:
    path "output.rds"

    """
    script.R "${my_function_rds}" "${my_input_rds}" output.rds
    """
}

workflow {

    function_rds = file( params.function_rds )
    input_rds = file( params.input_rds )

    my_script( function_rds, input_rds )
    my_script.out.view()
}
```

And your R script might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

FUN <- readRDS(args[1]);
input = readRDS(args[2]);
output = FUN(
  singleCell_data_input=input[[1]], savePath=input[[2]], tmpDirGC=input[[3]]
);
saveRDS(output, args[3])
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the complex answer. I would like to ask how should the nf file look like for the other way? The R script is changed every month and it would be useful to avoid changing the nf file as well

Comment: @DenisaBuzan No worries at all! As long as it's executable (and in the `bin` folder) all you should need is `script.R` in your script block. Also, make sure to include the `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` shebang at the top of your R script.

Comment: So the nf file should look like this:

#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
nextflow.enable.dsl=2 

process INDEX {


    """
    Rscript script.R
    """
}


workflow {
  //process is called like a function in the workflow block
  INDEX()
}

Comment: @DenisaBuzan, whoops... sorry I forgot about the file inputs! I've updated my answer, hopefully it makes a bit more sense!